# Edit display of commerce kickstart shopping cart

Tags: views, commerce, routes

How can I display the output of a view in a menu?

I made a views that displays the information I want correctly but I don't know how to display the  as a block in a menu. I've tried Menu attach blocks and Menu Views but couldn't get it to work.

Is there another option?

Answer (score 2):

Solved with the [Menu Minipanels](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> A system for building "megamenu" -style dropdown menus using [Mini Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels), which provides tremendous flexibility in what can be displayed.

The project page also points to an interesting [Click-by-click beginner's tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/984560#comment-3922442)